# How to save Core Data after users update software?

Tags: iphone, core-data

As far as I know, the Core Data store is stored in the application's documents directory.
If the user updates the application through App Store, all the data will be removed, right?
Can I save data to another place?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the data should be fine. However, you will have to perform a migration if you changed the data model in the new version of your app.

Comment: Hi gerry? Do you have any info about how to do that?